# Localised Strings Xcode 4 ... Copy .strings file Error Validation failed

Tags: localization, xcode4

How do I define localised strings in Xcode 4?

I assumed I could just add languages to InfoPlist.strings using the "Localization" property (File inspector, right panel).

...and then type in the "key" = "value"s in each localised version.

But I can't build the project.  I get this error:

> Copy .strings file Error Validation failed: The data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted.

Converting the text encoding to UTF 16 doesn't fix the problem.  Neither does quitting Xcode and starting it again.

Q1: How do I remedy these build errors?

By some fluke, I did once manage to get a test app to run adding a InfoPlist.strings (French) and (English).  I didn't get the error on the French strings file, but I did with the English.  So I left the English one alone, and just put a parameter in the French one.  However, in the simulator, set to French - the parameter wasn't picked up.  It reverted to the default specified in NSLocalizedString()

Q2: How do I get it working even if the build errors are remedied?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Could be as simple as a missing semi-colon at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.  However, although it builds and runs - it still doesn't work.  NSLocalizedString(@"default",@"greeting") gives me default all the time.

Comment: Do you have multiple .strings files? If so, NSLocalizedStringFromTable.

Comment: It works now.  Not sure why.  Maybe saving and loading again?

Comment: you problem was that NSLocalizedString(x,y) takes the **key** you want as the first argument (x) and a **comment** as the second (y) so what you wrote in your comment should have been: `NSLocalizedString(@"greeting", @"default")`

Comment: When there is a missing semi-colon, Xcode somehow doesn't show that warning until you close and re-open it. Project runs without any error, or warning. You just get keys as values. You see what the problem is just after restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 101):

I had same the issue finding the errors within the localization file...

Just use the tool plutil in the terminal to convert the file and you will get a proper error message with the line number.

> plutil -lint Localizable.strings

Response

> plutil[74058:707] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 422. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
>   Localizable.strings: Unexpected character " at line 1

Comment: Fully agree with @Jason; this immediately pinpointed my problem (which Xcode did not even find - it simply did not show the translations in the app). Good find, @TomTom !!

Comment: Possibly the best answer anywhere on StackOverflow! thank you (in my case it was some smart quotes which caused the problem)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a missing ';' but the same thing is tedious to find in a big file,

Answer (score 14):

yes just trawled through 500 translations

note the KISS in the second string is in Double quotes which are INSIDE another DOUBLE QUOTES
ERROR

```
"Before using KISS Remixer, you must agree to the terms and conditions of use." = "Vor der Nutzung des Remixers "KISS" müssen Sie die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen akzeptieren.";
```

This is OK

```
"Before using KISS Remixer, you must agree to the terms and conditions of use." = "Vor der Nutzung des Remixers KISS müssen Sie die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen akzeptieren.";
```

as is this (replace with single quotes INSIDE THE DOUBLE)

```
"Before using KISS Remixer, you must agree to the terms and conditions of use." = "Vor der Nutzung des Remixers 'KISS' müssen Sie die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen akzeptieren.";
```

TIP
USE a BINARY SEARCH to find the offending line.

1. get localized files back from translator.
2. copy all Loclaizable.strings into your project localized folders.
3. Open XCODE
4. Clean all - in iOS Device/all Simulators
5. Build
6. Copy .strings file Error Validation failed: The data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted.
7. Open the log navigator
8. See which of the translations is corrupt.
9. I opened the Localizable.strings in TextWrangler
   At bottom in tool bar Translator had sent back 
   UTF-16 file as

UTF-16 Little Endian
Changed it back to just 'UTF-16'
10. Cleaned build/Build
SAME ERROR

Somewhere in the file is

### Missing semicolon?

```
/* popup message */
"Save mix" = "Enregistrer le mixage";

/* popup message */
"Save mix" = "Enregistrer le mixage"
```

### "Extra "double quotes" inside double quotes"

WRONG

```
/* popup message */
"Save mix" = "Enregistrer le "mix" age"
```

RIGHT

```
/* popup message */
"Save mix" = "Enregistrer le mixage"
```

ALSO RIGHT

```
/* popup message */
"Save mix" = "Enregistrer le 'mix'age"
```

- remember there may be more than one error in a file
  I found "KISS" in double-double quotes in two places

Answer (score 8):

Check your file encoding. This is often caused by extended characters (like accented characters) and a non UTF encoding. In particular there is a bug in XCode 4 that if you copy accented characters into a strings file from Safari it will then save as Western Mac OS Roman.

Comment: Yes, my strings file somehow got re-set to UTF8 encoding, setting it to UTF16 allowed building to succeed.

Comment: Even though I only had valid UTF-8 characters, changing my files to UTF-16 fixed this error.

Answer (score 7):

It's a shame that XCode's syntax checker can't figure this out.

You can also copy the text into Text Wrangler (something I do after receiving a file from a translator) to check for properly quoted strings or run a regex checking for semicolons.   The syntax coloring in Text Wrangler will show mis-quoted (or mis-escaped) strings where XCode's strings editor currently does not.

Comment: TextMate does the same thing.

Comment: TextWrangler (which is now **BBEdit**) with its syntax coloring is a great way to check for issues on the file. In my case there were blank spaces which were not normal. `View > Text Display > Show Invisibles` will show you those problematic characters.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, `plutil -lint Localizable.strings` didn't help because the error message it produced was "`Unexpected character " at line 1`" when the real error was a `”` instead of a `"` on line 2340.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a problem of "quote" sign copy-pasted from a website, that was not accepted.

I should have detected that from syntax-highlighting not working, but I just read the source "quote sign, key, quote sign, equality sign, quote sign, value, quote sign... yup okay".

Answer (score 2):

If you use double quotation "" in your localisation, don't forget to escape them using a back slash.

Answer (score 2):

One should Check syntax like this

```
"Recharge_Data" = "Data";
```

1) "" should be there on proper place.

2) = should be checked.

3) ; should be there at end of statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 14, there is a convenient solution for this issue.

Follow these steps to resolve it:

1. Right-click on the affected `Localizable.strings` file.
2. Select `Open As` and then choose `ASCII Property List` from the submenu.
3. This action will prompt a popup that displays the line number and error message.

By following these steps, you can easily identify the problematic line and address the error in your `Localizable.strings` file.

See attached screenshots:
[image: Click on the localizable and select Open As menu]

[image: Xcode Alert Error Message]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469738/python-pywinauto-how-to-control-custom-gui-gui-made-by-c-or-c-want-control/76469744#76469744

Comment: Most useful answer

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. I had a about 60 pages long localization file, and had just one " too many - took a while to spot that

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue for a big localized file from an hour and apply all above steps won't solve my problem, finally what I am done with is, devide localize file into some ranges (parts), say part-a, b, c ... and cut those strings from file, and keep those in a text file, build the project again, unless and until I reached to the point, where only part-k was left, I found that by mistakenly I pressed **f** on my keyboard..fewww! it solved. I know this is not a solution but may be help to someone like me:)

Answer (score 0):

My friend did translation for me in Windows. I found, that changing encoding doesn't help,
so what I did: I commented all of the strings, and then I uncommented a few and pressed cmd-B, to find out which strings had problems. Then I rewrote problem strings manually and after that it worked.