# python pywinauto how to control custom gui. (gui made by C++ or C#) want control GUI and save file

Tags: python, save, edit, pywinauto

## <I modify question , depend on some comment, I have update my inquiry.>

>>>
I already study from various web site.
using pywinauto in PYTHON,, and save a file...
I can do it like notepad and notepad++ and etc...

but I can't success in 3rd party EXE file GUI control..
other team provide 3rd party exe file and I want menu click control via PYTHON . (pywinauto)
just click menu is working. and I success it..
this specific GUI also has same tab like notepad.
what I want do is

---- below process should work with Automation -----

1. click File
2. click save as
3. put and edit file name
4. click OK...

## problem is this is not like notepad or excel so education API is not work..
let me share my code below.... (updated code)

```
from pywinauto import Application, findwindows

# Connect to the target application
app = Application(backend='uia')
app.connect(process=20100)

# Select the "record" menu and click "Start Record"
app['Dialog'].menu_select("Run->Start Record")
# above working and pop up window.
# but after pop up window...
# human need to put name and click then we can move to next line...


# Wait for the "Open" dialog to appear
# pop up window name is Open / Btw,,, 
save_as_dialog = app['Open']

# Set the file name in the "Save As" dialog
save_as_dialog.child_window(title="File name:", control_type="Edit").set_edit_text("myfile.txt")

# Click the "Save" button
save_as_dialog.child_window(title="Save", control_type="Button").click()

# Wait for the file-saving process to complete
# Add appropriate delays or checks here if needed
```

I want full automation but after below command...

```
     app['Dialog'].menu_select("Run->Start Record")
```

automaticially pop up below window. (check below screenshot)

[image]

above screen capture... success to open pop up..
but i want automatically change name then want click open above...

so i expect below command work in sequence.
but before human click the UI..
Python is just waiting for next action..
it means we click pop up message then Python work next line..
but  i want this process by full automation.

```
save_as_dialog = app['Open']
```

additionally ,, i found this "OPEN" pop up message using find_element function.
check below screenshot...
realize that process number is same as main GUI,,, myprocess = 20100
you can see 'Open' instance.

[image]

please help and advise.

thanks
Wonyong Choi

Comment: please anyone can answer update inquiry??????